# Spring 3.1 + Hibernate 4.1 Propagation.Supports issue

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I'm migrating my project from Spring 3.0 +hibernate 3.6.x to S3.1 + H4.1

my new code is the following

```
    <context:component-scan base-package="x.y.z">
</context:component-scan>

<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
 <props>
    <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.x</prop> 
    <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop> 
    <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop> 
    <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop> 
  </props>
     </property>
        <property name="annotatedClasses">
      <list>
        <value>x.y.z.entities.Student</value>        
         </list>
    </property>
  </bean>

<bean id="transactionManager" 
            class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
  </bean>

<aop:config>
    <aop:pointcut id="daoServicePoint" 
            expression="execution(* x.y.z.StudentDao.*(..))"/>
    <aop:advisor advice-ref="txAdvice" pointcut-ref="daoServicePoint"/>
  </aop:config>

  <tx:advice id="txAdvice" transaction-manager="transactionManager">
    <tx:attributes>
      <tx:method name="save*" propagation="REQUIRED"/>
       <tx:method name="update*" propagation="REQUIRED"/>
       <tx:method name="delete*" propagation="REQUIRED"/>
     <tx:method name="get*" propagation="SUPPORTS" read-only="true"/>
    </tx:attributes>
  </tx:advice>
```

When running getStudent method marker as SUPPORTS and read only I'm getting

```
org.hibernate.HibernateException: No Session found for current thread
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.SpringSessionContext.currentSession(SpringSessionContext.java:97)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.getCurrentSession(SessionFactoryImpl.java:1024)
```

It used to be ok with Spring 3.0 and Hibernate 3.6.x now it was changed. I undestood from Spring forums that mow I need mark transaction REQUIRED if I need to use `sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();`

I used lower level technique in order to get maximum concurrent speed in my code.
When performing operations which require several get/save/update/ queries i did it the following way:

1. called method  marked as `SUPPORTS`.
2. Performed all get queries which are also marked as `SUPPORTS` inside
   first method.
3. then started queries which marked as `REQUIRED` inside the same method and this is a point
   where my roll-able back transaction begins.

I got good performance improvement using this technique, but marking all my methods as REQUIRED destroys it.

How can work around it?

Comment: Define "destroys" performance. That "lower level technique" doesn't sound like it's going to give you much of a performance improvement if in step 3 you still need to open a transaction, maybe with the exception of entities loaded in step 2 not being subject to dirty checking and caching. Or was the performance improvement you saw in the system as a whole, because of many calls to methods that never got to step 3?

Comment: Out of curiousity: have you measured the performance gain of your little trick? I doubt it's worth the effort unless you have some serious performance demands of your product.

Comment: @RasmusFranke, Fortunately it is not something that I invented. I just read this article. http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-ts5/index.html

Answer (score 3):

I encountered the same issue when experimenting with Spring and Hibernate 3 / 4.

It looks like this is a known issue, which is described in the following JIRA link.

https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-9020

It looks like Hibernate 4 version of SpringSessionContext does not open a new session if there is no existing transaction/session open and the called method @Transactional is configured with propagation = Propagation.SUPPORTS.

Comment: @thiagoh I apologize for the late reply. I haven't had the need to work on a solution for this because I haven't encountered the problem. I just looked for the reason why was this not working. There are a couple of suggestion on how to work around this problem in the comments section of the JIRA that I referenced.

One of them is to change the propagation to something different (e.g. PROPAGATION_REQUIRED).

The other is to implement a custom CurrentSessionContext class that creates a Session in this case and associate it to the SessionFactory that you are going ot use.

Answer (score 0):

i think you can still mark transaction as readonly. not sure if it has performance impact.

Comment: Why? i am using @Transactional(readOnly = true) and it is working fine with Hibernate 4 and spring 3.1