# Hibernate4, Spring4, Axis2 and @Transactional annotation not opening transaction: get is not valid without an active transaction

Tags: spring, hibernate, dependency-injection, apache-axis, transactional

I want to integrate my axis2 project with spring. I managed to load a spring applicationContext by following this guide.

> https://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/docs/spring.html

**IN SHORT**
Here's is my axis2 VersionService:

```
public class VersionService extends MyappService{

    private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(VersionService.class);

    @Autowired
    NewUserMyappDAO newUserMyappDAO;

    public Response getResponse(){
        Response response = new Response();
        UserMyapp ub = getTransaction();
        return response;
    }

    @Transactional
    public UserMyapp getTransaction(){
        return newUserMyappDAO.findById(13);
    }
}
```

The problem: when axis calls getResponse() method the dao manages to obtain the injected sessionFactory (and the hibernate session), but when the @Transactional is used on top of the method no transaction is opened before. That's why I get get:

```
 Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: get is not valid without active transaction
at org.hibernate.context.internal.ThreadLocalSessionContext$TransactionProtectionWrapper.invoke(ThreadLocalSessionContext.java:348)
at $Proxy45.get(Unknown Source)
at com.myapp.framework.model.dao.NewMyappDAO.findById(NewMyappDAO.java:35)
at com.myapp.ws.version.VersionService.getTransaction(VersionService.java:127)
at com.myapp.ws.version.VersionService.getResponse(VersionService.java:119)
```

What I want is having a getTransaction() method that automatically starts the transaction (Hibernate session.beginTransaction()) and rollbacks if something fails in it.

I also tried to remove

```
<prop key="hibernate.current_session_context_class">org.hibernate.context.internal.ThreadLocalSessionContext</prop>
```

but in this case spring fails to load the userMyAppDAO because of org.hibernate.HibernateException: No Session found for current thread

**IN DETAILS**
My applicationContext.xml looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache/spring-cache.xsd">


    <context:annotation-config />

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.myapp.framework.model.dao"></context:component-scan>

    <!-- Axis2 Web Service, but to Spring, its just another bean that has dependencies -->
    <bean id="versionService" class="com.myapp.ws.version.VersionService"/>

    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://db.myapp.com:3307/MyappAPI" />
        <property name="username" value="myapp" />
        <property name="password" value="myappculomyapp" />
    </bean>


    <bean id="sessionFactory"
                class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />

        <property name="packagesToScan">
            <list>
                <value>com.myapp.framework.model.dao</value>
            </list>
        </property>

        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect</prop>

                <prop key="hibernate.connection.CharSet">utf8</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.connection.characterEncoding">utf8</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.connection.useUnicode">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">false</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.use_sql_comments">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.globally_quoted_identifiers">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.connection.autocommit">false</prop>

                <prop key="hibernate.current_session_context_class">org.hibernate.context.internal.ThreadLocalSessionContext</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.transaction.factory_class">org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransactionFactory</prop>

                <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.cache.region.factory_class">org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegionFactory</prop>

            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionManager"
                class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    </bean>

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

</beans>
```

And here's the DAO and its superclass:

```
@Repository
public class NewUserMyappDAO extends NewMyappDAO<UserMyapp, Integer>{

    @Autowired
    public NewUserMyappDAO(SessionFactory sessionFactory){
        super(UserMyapp.class, sessionFactory);
    }
}

@Repository
public abstract class NewMyAppDAO<E, ID extends Serializable>
        implements IMyAppDAO<E, ID> {

    private final Class<E> entityClass;
    protected Session session;

    public NewMyAppDAO(Class<E> entityClass, SessionFactory sessionFactory) {

        this.entityClass = entityClass;
        this.session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    }

    public Class<E> getEntityClass() {
        return entityClass;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked" })
    public E findById(ID id) {
        Object obj = null;
        try {
            obj = session.get(getEntityClass(), id);
        } catch(ObjectNotFoundException e){
            return null;
        }
        return (E) obj;
    }
```

**EDIT**

The answer left by vp8106 seems to be going in the right way, but i tried to move a step backwords trying to manage transaction programmatically. What i did is to use the beginTransaction(), commitTransaction(), rollbackTransaction() and close() explicitly in getResponse() method. Even if the sessionFactory object is a singleton and it is initialized with

```
<prop key="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</prop>
```

no transaction is started and my dao still returns the same exception.

Comment: This `org.hibernate.HibernateException: No Session found for current thread` exception tells you that you haven't configured transactions correctly and that isn't fixed by simply using another current session context. Your `VersionService` isn't a spring managed bean and as such transactions won't work on that. Make sure that it is a fully sprnig managed bean (including proxy creation).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I don't understand how to check it. Axis is making it hard to understand. I mean, the userMyAppDAO is injected correctly so I thought I was working with a spring managed beans.

Comment: I found this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8846586/no-session-found-for-current-thread-spring-3-1-x-and-hibernate-4. It suggests to move the annotation driven settings to the servlet context instead of leaving them on the application one. It seems I should create an axis2-servlet.xml and pass it to the axis2 servlet in some way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is likely that Axis calls `getResponse` method of spring bean that is not marked with `@Transactional`. The fact is that spring creates a dynamic proxies for beans which have method annotated with `@Transactional`. This proxy wraps calls to transacted method starting transaction before and commiting after target method execution. But in your case method `getResponse` calls method `getTransaction` of **this** bean, not proxy. Thus transaction-aware code does not execute, and no transaction started.

The simpliest possible solution is to mark `getResponse` method with `@Transactional` instead of `getTransaction`. *Note: it will work only if `getResponse` is called on spring-generated proxy, which is not clear from stacktrace you provided.*

**EDIT** 
In Spring environment you should use

```
<prop key="hibernate.current_session_context_class">org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.SpringSessionContext</prop>
```

It binds hibernate session lifecycle to the Spring's HibernateTransactionManager.
In order to start, commit or rollback transactions HibernateTransactionManager's `.getTransaction(...)`, `commit(...)` or `rollback(...)` should be used instead of hibernate Session's methods. To manage transactions programmatically it would be better to use `TransactionTemplate` which helps you to avoid writing boilerplate code to begin, commit, or rollback transactions.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I just edited the answer in order to understand if it's spring or hibernate.

Comment: It is still throwing org.hibernate.HibernateException: No Session found for current thread at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.SpringSessionContext.currentSession(SpringSessionContext.java:106) while loading the app into tomcat. Giving a look to the code I see that in SpringSessionContext class the row TransactionSynchronizationManager.getResource(this.sessionFactory); returns a null value. It probably has to do to the fact that the beans are loading as root context, not servlet context.

Comment: It came out i was using the same Session object for all my hibernate queries (without getting it every time from sessionFactory). <prop key="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</prop> seems to work using <prop key="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</prop> and programmatic transaction management.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to vp816 and M. Deinum I managed to understand what's happening.

1. **The big mistake here** was that I was using the same private Session field object every time I was calling findById method of NewMyAppDAO. Using the protected getSession() method allows to use session correctly.

   @Repository
    public abstract class NewMyAppDAO
    implements IMyAppDAO {

   ```
   private final Class<E> entityClass;
   protected SessionFactory sessionFactory;

   public NewMyAppDAO(Class<E> entityClass, SessionFactory sessionFactory) {

       this.entityClass = entityClass;
       this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
   }

   protected Session getSession(){
       return  this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
   }
   ```

   }
2. Using **programmatic transaction management** we have to set the property

   ```
   <prop key="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</prop>
   ```

   Spring setting:

   ```
   <tx:annotation-driven>
   ```

   in this case is useless.
3. If we want to use **Spring Annotation Driven transactions** we have to:
    
   a) delete `hibernate.current_session_context_class` property from sessionFactory bean configuration
   b) adding spring settings 
   `<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
   <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
   </bean>
   <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />`

   c) Using @Transactional annotation in spring beans except from axis2 services. In fact their loading seems to happen in such a way that spring doesn't manage to create the proxy. In my case the solution has been to create a spring-annotated service and set its method as transactional.

   @Service
   public class VersionHandler {

   ```
   @Autowired
   NewUserMyappDAO newUserMyappDAO;

   @Transactional
   public UserMyapp getUserMyapp(int transactionId){
       return newUserMyappDAO.findById(transactionId);
   }
   ```

   }